# Converting GEE Javascript to Python using geemap not working

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm looking to convert my code to calculate the mean 30 year precipitation from ERA5 in GEE into Python so that I can run it in the ee python command line tool. I tried using the geemap conversion tool, but it can't quite convert this bit of code I wrote to find the mean precipitation over 30 years.

I've tried to convert my script manually and have listed the three versions below. 1st the code that works in GEE, 2nd the code outputted by geemap, and 3rd the one I've been working on. How do I make the third one work in the same way as the first?

**Correct GEE Code**

```
var era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY").select(['total_precipitation']); //band of interest
  
var mean_30_yr_precip = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1990, 2020)
  .map(function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year), 1, 1);
    return era5
      .filterDate(startDate, startDate.advance(1, 'year'))
      .map(function (monthlyprecip) {
        return monthlyprecip//.multiply(1000); // convert to mm
      })
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()) // add all the months for total precip per year
      //.divide(12); // go from total precipitation to mean precipitation

  })
).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()); // get the mean of all of the means over the years
```

**Failed GEE to Python Conversion Code using geemap**

```
era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY").select(['total_precipitation']); #band of interest

mean_30_yr_precip = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1990, 2020)

def func_yty (year):
    startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year), 1, 1)
    return era5 \
      .filterDate(startDate, startDate.advance(1, 'year')) \
      .map(function (monthlyprecip) {
        return monthlyprecip#.multiply(1000); # convert to mm
      }) \
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()) 
      #.divide(12); # go from total precipitation to mean precipitation \
  .map(func_yty)











).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()); # get the mean of all of the means over the years
```

**My attempted python code**

```
years_lst = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1990, 2020))
def frost_calculator(years_list):
    for year in years_list:
        startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year), 1, 1)
        endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year')
        filtered_collection = collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).lt(273.15)
        reduced_collection = filtered_collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).gt(6)
        frost_var = reduced_collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).gt(0) # Number of freezing years
        return frost_var
frost = frost_calculator(years_lst)
nonfrost = frost.eq(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your python code you are using a client-side function (`for` loop) over server-side functions. That's the first error.

Also, `.lt` doesn't work over image collections, only over images. So if you want to obtain the annual precipitation use the following approach:

```
years_lst = ee.List.sequence(1990, 2020)
def frost_calculator(year):
    startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year), 1, 1)
    endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year')
    reduced_collection = collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
    return reduced_collection
annual_pp = years_lst.map(frost_calculator)
```

You can add the logic functions (`lt` and `gt`) inside `frost_calculator` (I would call it `annual_sum`) with `reduced_collection`